# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre de una imagen MEDIA que cargue por formulario antes de guardarlo en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

estoy trabajando en Django, desde el template estoy creando un formulario que capta toda la información y una imagen, y lo hace de forma correcta.

```
            formulario=FormularioRecarga(request.POST, request.FILES)          
            if formulario.is_valid():
                formulario=formulario.save(commit=False)
                usuario=request.user.id
                mensajero=Mensajero.objects.get(usuario_id=usuario) 
                formulario.mensajero_id=mensajero.id
                formulario.save()
```

Pero quiero cambiar el nombre de la imagen que adjuntan antes del ".save()"

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano, muchas gracias.